# How can I fill the complete entity after persist?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I am using the Hibernate persistence API. I have two entities, you can check the Parent of these: (The Child entity does not contain any reference to the Parent - because it is not necessary business logically.)

```
@Entity(...)
public class ParentEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    // ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL }) // losing JPA's portability
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Set<ChildEntity> children;

    // ...
}
```

When I persist a new Parent entity, a DB trigger is executed. This trigger inserts some Children by default values. But after persisting, the children are not in the collection. *How can I solve this?* Here is my Dao method:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
@Override
public Parent addParent(String name) {
    Parent temp = new Parent(name);
    entityManager.persist(temp);

    return entityManager.find(Parent.class, temp.getId()); // return temp;
}
```

Thank you in advance very much for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Parent temp = new Parent(name);
entityManager.persist(temp);
```

If i get you properly,

You are creating a new parent object (without any child entity) and persisting it.
So a parent object without any child is persisted in DB.

When you do

```
entityManager.find(Parent.class, temp.getId());
```

You can't expect to have a parent class with child entities.

Since you are persisting the child object by a db trigger, there must be some way to put parent_id (**tem.getId()**/**parent.getId()**) in them

There is no other to way to find child objects of the persisted parent.

Comment: How else can I load the Children entities? Is exist any workaround?

Comment: when db triggered is executed to insert child object there must be a way to set parent_id to those child object